# Trigonometric equations with more than one function

Tags: trigonometry

This is a general question about how to solve trigonometric equations which involve different functions. I have been multiplying and dividing the functions but have not been able to attain an expression with just one function. I'm encountering questions such as:

$$3\tan A - 2\cot A = 5 $$

and

$$6\sin A\cos A + 3\sin A = 2\cos A + 1$$

What is the method or process that I would use to change all the terms to like functions?

Comment: If you have $\tan$ and $\cot$, use that $\cot z = \frac{1}{\tan z}$. You get a quadratic equation (for $\tan z$) here.

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that a moment ago. I had changed it to sines and coses and had no luck in multiplying/subtracting/dividing.

Comment: For the second, you can use a substitution $\sin A = x$, $\cos A = \sqrt{1- x^2}$, and try and solve for $x$. IN this way, you can always change any trig equation to a function in 1 variable (which could be very ugly). There is no 'general way' of solving, though there are several different methods of approach that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second equation can be rewritten as
$$6\sin{\alpha}\cos {\alpha} + 3\sin{\alpha} = 2\cos{\alpha} + 1,\\
3\sin{\alpha}(2\cos{\alpha} + 1)=2\cos{\alpha} + 1, \\
(3\sin{\alpha}-1)(2\cos{\alpha} + 1)=0.$$
Then 
$$\sin{\alpha}=\dfrac{1}{3}$$
or $$\cos{\alpha} =-\dfrac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clearing that up. I seem to miss the simple things like that.I guess I just have to keep my eyes open.